# Git Corrupt Index

Tags: git, svn, version-control, coexistence

When you migrate from Subversion to Git, you want a small period of having both Subversion and Git (coexistence of subversion and git).
During the coexistence phase you have to commit to both. Subversion does understand the commits and updates, but Git does not.
Git has an error with its indexes which says files are changes while the physic content is not. Git commands status (showing a difference), while git diff does not.
To solve the problem do

```
 $ git rm --cached -r .
 $ git reset --hard
```

And all is ok. But this method also removes all (maybe made) changes (not bulletproof approach).
My question is how to    ℎ   while there is no  difference. Please note I have read articles on StackOverflow and others on the coexistence of Git and Subversion, and if you are interested you may read a more in depth article on https://www.harmfrielink.nl/wiki/index.php/Co-Existence_Subversion_&_Git.
My questions are

- Who has the same problem?
- Who knows the cause of the problem?
- What is the best solution?

Comment: do you have any questions?

Comment: Added the questions.

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with an interaction between Git and Subversion.  How do you have your line endings configured in Git?

Comment: I am only using OSX devices for development. So do I need the extra configuration for line endings? I think that is not necessary.
Please understand the workflow, first I commit in Git then in Subversion. On the other clients i update Git first and when I also update Subversion the difference is there. Git status has a status-difference without a physical difference in Git, Subversion is up-to-date without any difference.
Sorry for my late answer but I have moved.